# android, how to use "dumpsys meminfo" programmatically

Tags: android-memory, dumpsys

Would like to use "dumpsys meminfo" programmatically to printout the memory usage for the application at certain time points,

added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DUMP" />`, and tested on emulator with the following code, but got exception:
"java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "adb": error=13, Permission denied"

```
    fun dump() {

        val process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb shell dumpsys meminfo  com.testapp.demo")
        process.waitFor()
        val bufferedReader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()))
        var buffer: String? = ""

        while (bufferedReader.readLine().also({ buffer = it }) != null) {

            Log.i("+++", buffer)

        }
        buffer = ""
        val buffered = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()))
        while (buffered.readLine().also({ buffer = it }) != null) {
            Log.w("+++", buffer)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` runs inside the tablet, So `adb shell` is unnecessary command.

You can thus try this...?

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("dumpsys meminfo com.testapp.demo")
```

Comment: @Simas Joneliunas 
Thank you for correcting my English!